# Multiple Get methods in Rest API controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest, restful-url

Hello I have added an extra get method in a API controller.

original Get

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetParticipants")]
public IActionResult GetParticipants([FromQuery] Guid conversationId, [FromQuery] ContextServiceModel context)
{
  ... stuff ...
}
```

New Get

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetThreadParticipants")]
public IActionResult ThreadParticipants([FromQuery] Guid parentMessageId)
{
   ... stuff ...
}
```

My question is does this follow Rest? Is it okay to route them this way and have different parameters?

Comment: Have you tried this out ? Are you facing any error or exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many Action methods as you want in your controller until and unless no action methods have same routes.

**Routing**

1. Conventional Routing
   Defined in WebAPI.config
2. Attribute Routing
   Directly defined on action method

More on attribute routing

[Attribute routing Web API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)